# Adding two outcomes and comparing with a third outcome

Tags: anova, t-test, group-differences

I did two experiments, with component A and component B respectively, and the outcome that I have is "mass loss" for those two components. Now, there is a third experiment where both components are used together and there is a combined mass loss. Lets call it C. I'm trying to perform stats to see if the A+B is greater than or equal to C. Each experiment has 5 samples each. Is it appropriate to iteratively sum the samples of A and B to get a combined mass loss and then compare it with C using a t-test? What other statistical test would you recommend?

Comment: Are samples for A, B and C independent? Or are you performing A, B and C experiments on the same specimens?

Comment: The samples of A, B and C are independent..

Answer (score 0):

Since A, B and C are independent (according to comment), A+B and C are independent and therefore a t-test for independent samples is adequate to tell if mean of A+B is different from mean of C. However, I wouldn't sum iteratively observations from A and B (A1+B1, A2+B2...). I would sum all possible pairs in A and B (A1+B1, A1+B2...). Alternatively, variance of A+B could be computed summing variances of A and B.

Of course, assumptions of t-test must hold for A+B and C, but if A and B are normal, A+B will be normal, too.